# Start JavaFX application on Banana Pi Pro

Tags: javafx, framebuffer, banana-pi

I have problem with starting JavaFX application on Banana Pi Pro(Bananian OS) system.
From my view the problem in GPU configuration. I have configured it by this instruction http://wiki.lemaker.org/BananaPro/Pi:GPU
All things configured for framebuffer version because javaFX executes in framebufer. On appllication start everytime the same error like on picture.
This application works without any problems on Raspberry Pi and on Windows system. Can somebody help in this question?
[image]

[image: After adding additional parameter]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had problems some time ago while trying to run JavaFX on ARM with Mali-400 graphic driver. I am unsure if this GPU and its driver is/will be supported, maybe I'm wrong or it will be supported later by OpenJFX developers. In my case it turned out to be an issue of the Mali driver itself.

You can still run the Javafx program using the software renderer, adding **-Dprism.order=sw** and **-Djavafx.platform=fb** (try also with other platforms) to the command line. Also, adding -Dprism.verbose=true may help you to follow the steps performed by the underlying JavaFX implementation before saying there is no pipeline for GPU rendering. In any case, JavaFX is not able to use 3D acceleration on your platform.

I already asked in Oracle forums but I got no answers. In the question you'll find additional details.
https://community.oracle.com/message/12488945#12488945

Also, you should ensure that 3d acceleration is working on your platform and it is configured correctly on framebuffer and not on X11 only (if active).

Note: Remember that Oracle itself is not supporting JavaFX on ARM any more, due to the large number of different platforms. Also, 3d drivers provided by the manufacturer are probably not open sourced, and from my knowledge Raspberry PI was one of the few ARM platforms that were supported by Oracle's JavaFX. For more info: [Java Development Kit for ARM Release Notes 8 Update 33](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk-8u33-arm-relnotes-2406696.html)

Comment: Hello, i can't find any information about if javafx is support with Mali400 GPU. I attached in my first post image with result with -Dprism.verbose=true. Maybe you can help me

Comment: With -Dprism.order=sw i also can't start my app(

Comment: Egl Error is 12299, or 0x300B, with is EGL_BAD_NATIVE_WINDOW. I would ask you if you ever had success to run the same application under X11.

Comment: Here is a reference to what I was looking at while saying that Mali-400 could be still not supported: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090336?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:worklog-tabpanel. Also, I edited the answer above with additional information (such as another command line option you may try). Tell me if you see any difference...

Comment: At first, thank you for your help)) So after some testing time i have new results:
If i start just with -Dprism.order=sw i have error like on third image.

i have updated GTK "sudo apt-get install libswt-gtk-3-jni libswt-gtk-3-java", after that my app is starts with parameters 
-Djavafx.platform=gtk -Djavafx.order=sw, but i can see only buttons in my app, no any edits, labels, menu.

Comment: The best result i have under X11 with next parameters: -Djavafx.platform. In this case on app start i have warning message "No settings found for javafx.platform=", but i have complettely worked application, with all controls and all functionality, just with really slow performance. So do you know if it's possible to increase performance?

Comment: Also for information, my app not used any 3d, i'm using only tratsition effects for to show images

Comment: JavaFX uses OpenGL as defaul renderer to speed up 2d and 3d drawings with GPU, even for the controls. Obviously a software renderer makes things very slow. You could try with OpenJFX, and this will be my attempt within some months, instead of using JFX as deployed by Oracle. If I have other news, I'll keep you informed. By the way, Mali-400 is NOT supported yet:https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Platforms

Comment: Ok.Thanks again for help. So currently i'm back to raspberry